# How to show that the Grassmannian is irreducible as a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

How to show that the Grassmannian is irreducible as a variety?

I have no idea.

Comment: Find a map from an affine space to it with dense image.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way: Note that there is a transitive group action on the Grassmannian. The group $GL(n)$ act transitively on the Grassmannian. So choose a smooth point $P \in \mathbb{G}r(k,n)$. Then by acting on $P$ with $GL(n)$, we conclude that all points are smooth and that the Grassmannian is connected.

But smooth connected varieties are irreducible.

Comment: You can go directly to irreducibility, since the image of an irreducible is irreducible, and you have your surjective map by picking the orbit of a point.

Comment: @AreaMan You mean GL(n) is irreducible? So how to prove this?

Comment: @AreaMan It seems we need the field to be algebraic closed.

Comment: @AreaMan I see... It is simply by GL(n) is the open set of $K^{n^2}$. And It does not need the field to be algebraic closed. At first I think it is a counter example when the filed is R, since GL(n, R) seems not to be connected. But then I found I was thinking of the ordinary topology.

Comment: @Akatsuki It is about the Zariski topology, and it is actually a point-set topological argument. $X$ is reducible if there are two nonempty open subsets of $X$ whose intersection is empty. It is easy to see that this property passes equivalently to open subspaces, so $GL(n,K)$ is irreducible if and only if $M(n,K) = K^{n^2}$ is irreducible, which it is.